# Unable to access external storage

Tags: usb, kubuntu, fstab

Whenever I insert an external USB storage device in my USB port on my new Slimbbok pro x15 running Kubuntu 18.04 I get:

```
An error occurred while accessing '1,9 GiB Removable Media', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: unknown filesystem type 'swap'
```

The devices work fine on my thinkpad x240 (Kubuntu 19.10). I have tested with a USB stick and an external HDD.

Any ideas?

My /etc/fstab (I am not sure this is relevant)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root    /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1727d751-47db-4665-9ae5-2c2c8970c2ca       /boot   ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7F24-5C01  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1  none    swap    sw      0       0
/dev/sdb1       none    ext4    defaults        0       0
```

Shall I remove the last line?

Comment: If the external USB storage device is seen as `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdb1` does not contain an ext4 file system, the last line in your fstab may cause problems. If you still want to connect an ext4 drive sometimes, it would be a better idea to use UUID instead of device name, and instead of `none` as mountpoint you could have a predefined one, but use the mount option `noauto`, for example `defaults,noauto` in the fourth field.

Comment: Thank you, you can put this in an answer. Removing the last line in fstab solved my Problem. And I will make a New fstab Entry for my ecternal HDD.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you solve the problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the partition's UUID instead of a device name in fstab

If the external USB storage device is seen as `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdb1` does not contain an ext4 file system, the last line in your fstab may cause problems.

If you still want to connect an ext4 drive sometimes, it would be a better idea to use UUID instead of device name, and instead of `none` as mountpoint you could have a predefined one, but use the mount option `noauto`, for example `defaults,noauto` in the fourth field.