# Cannot mount USB Stick on Ubuntu 22.04:

Tags: usb, mount, 22.04

On Ubuntu 22.04, when I try to mount my USB Stick on my file explorer (right-click on it in the side bar, then 'Mount'). A window appears with "Failed to mount USB Stick, an operation is already pending". I can't figure out what is this operation. This behavior is new. The file system on the stick is ext4.

Thank you for your help

Edit:

```bash
$ sudo lsblk -e7 -f
NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL        UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                                  
└─sda1 ext4   1.0   MediaRange   592b312e-cc07-47ae-860b-ff394c90df22                
sdb                                                                                  
nvme0n1
│                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1
│      ntfs         Wiederherstellung
│                                BA44D34044D2FDD7                                    
├─nvme0n1p2
│      vfat   FAT32              06D3-FE6F                              52.7M    45% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3
│                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p4
│      ntfs                      9CF0D584F0D564D4                                    
├─nvme0n1p5
│      ntfs                      B0F8812AF880F040                                    
├─nvme0n1p6
│      ext4   1.0                d1e12f70-1d43-4777-8eac-7d66e2905a93                
├─nvme0n1p7
│      ext4   1.0                67b85685-b45b-41bd-93ee-3e046062aec4   26.1G    44% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                                                                    /
├─nvme0n1p8
│      swap   1                  0e3aa3fe-0c2f-4393-841e-09572ea43d30                [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p9
       ext4   1.0                0bd2c977-65e0-4e7f-b4ad-54914aac258a   33.8G    63% /home
```

```bash
$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=67b85685-b45b-41bd-93ee-3e046062aec4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=06D3-FE6F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p9 during installation
UUID=0bd2c977-65e0-4e7f-b4ad-54914aac258a /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p8 during installation
UUID=0e3aa3fe-0c2f-4393-841e-09572ea43d30 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=592b312e-cc07-47ae-860b-ff394c90df22 /mnt/usbdata  ext4  noatime,noauto 0  0
```

```bash
$ ls -ld /mnt/usbdata/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  7 13:26 /mnt/usbdata/
```

```bash
$ mount | grep ext4
/dev/nvme0n1p7 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p7 on /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell type ext4 (ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p9 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

EDIT:
I still have not found a solution for this. With GParted, I can see that the data are still there on the stick, but when I try to mount it to a directory, it keeps trying forever, without finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create the mount point

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/usbdata
```

and find the UUID with `lsblk`

```
lsblk -e7 -o name,fstype,uuid
```

and edit your file `/etc/fstab` according to the advice in the manual page

```
man fstab
```

and add the following line (use your own file system's UUID):

```
UUID=4c518694-d97c-4910-bb7b-eeb6a6b73874  /mnt/usbdata  ext4  noatime 0  0
```

If you do not always keep the drive (USB stick with the ext4 file system) connected, you should add the boot option `noauto` (so `noatime,noauto` in field #4).

With the `noauto` option, you should mount the drive by the following command in a terminal window,

```
sudo mount /mnt/usbdata
```

This should start working after reboot.

---

The following links may help explaining/describing what to do.

Answers at AskUbuntu:

[Adding new SATA SSD hard drive, not showing up in file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431937/adding-new-sata-ssd-hard-drive-not-showing-up-in-file-manager/1431961#1431961)

[Unable to access external storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208518/unable-to-access-external-storage/1208595#1208595)

[Formatting a USB flash drive as ext4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416536/formatting-a-usb-flash-drive-as-ext4/851203#851203)

[How to create partition for data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862181/how-to-create-partition-for-data/862195#862195)

An Ubuntu help page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS#Final_system_tweaks

Comment: Thank you @sudodus for the comment. I did what you suggested but `sudo mount /mnt/usbdata` is hanging in the terminal. Isn't there any log I can find in order to see what's going on?

Comment: You can run `lsblk -e7 -f` and `cat /etc/fstab` and paste the output of both commands into your original question. Please indent each line 4 spaces in order to render it as `code` to make it easy to read. Then write a comment to me (@sudodus) so that I will get an alert about it. - By the way, did you enter the sudo password correctly?

Comment: Done! The password was right. @sudodus

Comment: I don't see anything wring in that output; 1. Please write also the output of `ls -ld /mnt/usbdata` (as code) and of `mount | grep ext4` into your original question; 2. Did you reboot the computer after editing `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: 1. Done @sudodus
2. Yes, I rebooted the computer after having edited `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @Maxclac, Thanks for the added details. I cannot see anything wrong, and I have no advice right now. Maybe I can suggest something later on. Maybe someone else can suggest something that solves your problem ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148457/discussion-between-sudodus-and-maxclac).

Comment: Did you ever try running fsck on the unmounted partition?  Might be a filesystem error.